# InputStreamBody in HttpMime 4.0.3 settings for content-length

Tags: java, post, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a multi part formdata post through my java code. Can someone tell me how to set Content Length in the following?? There seem to be headers involved when we use InputStreamBody which implements the ContentDescriptor interface. Doing a getContentLength on the InputStreamBody gives me -1 after i add the content. I subclassed it to give contentLength the length of my byte array but am not sure if other headers required by ContentDescriptor will be set for a proper POST.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(myURL);
ContentBody cb = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray), myMimeType, filename);
//ContentBody cb = new ByteArrayBody(bytearray, myMimeType, filename);

MultipartEntity mpentity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
mpentity.addPart("key", new StringBody("SOME_KEY"));
mpentity.addPart("output", new StringBody("SOME_NAME"));
mpentity.addPart("content", cb);
httpPost.setEntity(mpentity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the ByteArrayBody class you have commented out.

I wrote it because I faced the same issue you did. The original Jira ticket is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1014

So, since you already have a byte[], either upgrade HttpMime to the latest version, 4.1-beta1, which includes this class. Or copy the code from the Jira issue into your own project.

The ByteArrayBody class will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I am getting the following error when using the class... Do the httpmime and httpclient both have to be 4.1-beta1? That is the current setup i have after your suggestion... <code> java.lang.AbstractMethodError at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:169) at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:191) at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:180)
 at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:97)
</code>

Comment: Hi, Also, how do i set Content-Encoding for the multipart message? I am getting null when i query for encoding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, both should be 4.1-beta1

Comment: You can set the header to the value you want and add it to the request.

Comment: I've been trying to make things work with ByteArrayBody but it doesn't work. Strangely, using FilePart works. But i need ByteArray to be passed, not some file on hard disk. I've tried MultiPartRequestEntity with FilePartSource and ByteArrayPartSource and that too worked only for FilePartSource and not ByteArrayPartSource. Do i have to do something to make ByteArrays work or does HttpClient have a problem with ByteArrays?